# Deploying new versions of Angular App to AWS S3

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I currently have an Angular APP deployed to AWS S3/Cloudfront and everything is working fine.

However, I want to know what is the best process to follow in order to deploy a new version of the App without interfering with the old one (users currently using the app should still be able to use it fine).

Currently, if I deploy a new version, users might get errors loading angular's chunks from modules and etc. Only fixed by refreshing the app, which is not nice).

Looked everywhere for this but could't find a recommended approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CloudFront :

1. Upload your code
2. Invalidate cache in cloudfront

Step to invalidate cache forcefully:

1. Select the distribution for which you want to invalidate files.

   Choose Distribution Settings.

   Choose the Invalidations tab.

   Choose Create Invalidation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html
For the files that you want to invalidate, enter one invalidation path per line. For information about specifying invalidation paths, see Specifying the Files to Invalidate.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serving-outdated-content-s3/

Another way to user versioning in content like js/css/images etc.

Comment: Hi, I'm currently using invalidation. I can deploy new versions and everything works fine. The problem is with users that are already logged in the app and when they try to access some other module, they receive an error because the module does not exist anymore. I would like for both the old and the new version to coexist.

Comment: There is no other way to do it.